# I am getting an Error " cannot determine size of graphic ( no boundingBox) Overleaf

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, bounding-box, dvipdfmx

I am getting an Error " cannot determine size of graphic ( no boundingBox)

```
\documentclass{proposalnsf}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
%\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square}
%\usepackage[pdflatex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tabularx}


% See this file for a set of pre-defined journal abbreviations
\input{journal-abbreviations.tex} 

\newcommand{\degrees}{$\!\!$\char23$\!$}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centerline{References cited}}

% This handles hanging indents for publications
\def\rrr#1\\{\par
\medskip\hbox{\vbox{\parindent=2em\hsize=6.12in
\hangindent=4em\hangafter=1#1}}}

\def\baselinestretch{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{graphical abstract.pdf}
     \caption{zzzzz.}
       \label{fig: zzzz}
\end{figure}


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thepage} {E--\arabic{page}}


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,draft}


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand{\thepage} {G--\arabic{page}}
\noindent{\Large \bf BUDGET JUSTIFICATION}

\end{document}
```

I have tried different things such as using dvipdfmx and pdflatex but nothing worked!

Comment: latex/dvips can not include pdf files. use pdflatex (in the sidebar of overleaf, not a change in your document)

Comment: it worked! thank you so much